# Will deleting column data reduce database size?

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table with several columns, one of which is a CLOB containing large XML project file data. That one column accounts for 99% of the size of that table, and the table has grown to several Gb. Our DBA needs to migrate the database and wants to reduce the size as much as possible beforehand. We can't lose any rows from that table but we would be safe in clearing out the data in that particular CLOB column. Would updating the table to remove that data reduce the overall size (I assume if it did it would be in conjunction with some administrative re-indexing action or something)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any CLOB data, drop that column:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id     number,
  3     cclob  clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id, cclob) values (1, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> alter table test drop column cclob;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, create a new table with primary key column and CLOB column:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------------------
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)
 DNAME                                              VARCHAR2(14)
 LOC                                                VARCHAR2(13)
 CCLOB                                              CLOB

SQL> create table new_test as select deptno, cclob from test;

Table created.

SQL> alter table test drop column cclob;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Now you can move the new, *lightweight* table to another server. If you need some of CLOB data, you can update the new table (on a new server) as

```
SQL> update test_on_new_server a set
  2    a.cclob = (select b.cclob
  3               from test_from_old_server b
  4               where b.deptno = a.deptno
  5              )
  6  where a.loc = 'NEW YORK';
```